# What is the most efficient way to read a lot of integers (doubles) from text file in C#?

Tags: c#, optimization, matrix, double, integer

If i have to read a huge matrix of integers from a file, what would be the most efficient way to do so in C#?

Example :

```
n m // n - number of rows m - number of columns
a11  ... a1m
    ...
an1 ...  anm
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, how did it perform, and how much faster do you *need* it to perform?

Comment: Personally, if the file format is consistent, for convenience I'd consider using FileHelpers.Net - http://www.filehelpers.com/. However, as Jon Skeet says, without knowing more, it's hard to recommend anything.

Comment: I'm reading it line by line, splitting it and parsing it after. I was thinking If i could read until first space and parse the int I got, rather then reading entire line, cause right now I'm passing through the same data more then once.

Comment: You can use a MemoryMappedFile rather than standard file IO. this can really make a difference depending on a few factors (filesize, page layout etc), see http://www.dotnetperls.com/memorymappedfile-benchmark

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it depends what you mean by efficient, in terms of speed once loaded loading into an multidimensional array and using this would be very quick.

In terms of only using the resources that you need, streaming the rows line by line would be best.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, after reading the whole text from file, you can use [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) class to match all numbers (using Matches(String) method) and retrieve an object of class [Matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/e7sf90t3.aspx). All the number under String form are stored in this object and you can obtain the numbers by parsing it from these string.

Comment: -1 for Mike asked for efficient solution and using regex in this case is slow and pointless